# Join an Existing Database to An Availability Group

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, smo, alwayson

I'm porting some existing (dynamic) SQL to C# via [the SMO namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo(v=sql.110).aspx). I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to join an existing database to my AlwaysOn Availability Group, though. The SMO namespace has a Database object and an AvailabilityDatabase object, but the two seem to be somewhat orthogonal...I can't see a way to move back and forth between the two concepts. In our existing implementation we create the database, perform some operations on it, create a full backup and then join it to the Availability Group. I'm trying to recreate this workflow in SMO, but getting hung up at the join to Availability Group step. If I do this...

```
AvailabilityGroup ag = new AvailabilityGroup(sqlServer, myExistingAgName);
AvailabilityDatabase agDb = new AvailabilityDatabase(ag, myExistingDbName);
agDb.JoinAvailablityGroup();
```

The operation fails and tells me that the AvailabilityDatabase hasn't been created yet. However, if I do this...

```
AvailabilityGroup ag = new AvailabilityGroup(sqlServer, myExistingAgName);
AvailabilityDatabase agDb = new AvailabilityDatabase(ag, myExistingDbName);
agDb.Create();
agDb.JoinAvailablityGroup();
```

The operation fails and tells me that the creation of the AvailabilityDatabase failed. Although the error message doesn't explicitly state this, I would assume the reason for the failure was that a DB by the name of `myExistingDbName` already exists, which is expected. I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental here, but the MSDN documentation isn't very illustrative, and I'm not having any luck finding any tutorials/examples of this sort of thing online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the database to the Availability Group on primary, I used the following...

```
// note that the Availability Group is instantiated differently than above
AvailabilityGroup ag = sqlServer.AvailabilityGroups[availabilityGroup];
AvailabilityDatabase agDb = new AvailabilityDatabase(ag, database);
agDb.Create();
```

After restoring the database on the secondary server(s), here's what I used to join it to the Availability Group...

```
AvailabilityGroup ag = sqlServer.AvailabilityGroups[availabilityGroup];
ag.AvailabilityDatabases[database].JoinAvailablityGroup();
```